# Lista dinâmica em ordem alfabética?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Dentro dessa `array` de minha *lista dinâmica*, o conteúdo dela está retornando de forma *desordenada*, como faço para colocá-la em ordem alfabética?

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="nome">Categoria do Produto</label>
        <select id="categoria_id" name="categoria_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Selecione</option>

            @foreach (App\Categoria::all() as $categoria)
                <option value="{{ $categoria->id }}">{{ $categoria->nome }}</option>
            @endforeach

        </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize `App\Categoria::orderBy('nome')->get()`, apesar que isso não é um boa recomendação. Deveria vir o dado pronto para `View` do `Controller`, mas está aí a forma como deveria ser.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome">Categoria do Produto</label>
    <select id="categoria_id" name="categoria_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Selecione</option>

        @foreach (App\Categoria::orderBy('nome')->get() as $categoria)
            <option value="{{ $categoria->id }}">{{ $categoria->nome }}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>
</div>
```

---

<sub>***Recomendação***</sub>

A prática ideal seria enviar somente o dado pronto para a sua `View`:

***Controller***

```
public function exibe()
{
    $data['categories'] = \App\Categoria::orderBy('nome')->get();
    return view('view1', $data);
}
```

***View***

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome">Categoria do Produto</label>
    <select id="categoria_id" name="categoria_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Selecione</option>

        @foreach ($categories as $categoria)
            <option value="{{ $categoria->id }}">{{ $categoria->nome }}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>
</div>
```

<sup>***Isso é um exemplo, dados fictícios***</sup>

<sup>Referencias:</sup>

- [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)
- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries)
- [selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects)

Comment: Perfeito, porem esta vindo duplicado tem algum artigo ou alguma dica de leitura onde eu consigo mais informações nas minhas criações

Comment: @leonardosilva duplicato o que? porque esse código é referente ao que está na sua base de dados, a sua base tem item duplicados?

Comment: @leonardosilva e ai o problema foi resolvido?

Comment: nem consegui amigo, acabei deixando de lado por um tempo, para voltar aos meus projetos iniciais, porem hoje eu voltei a dar continuidade a eles.